# What happens when each player has to draw a card with no cards left in their library?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I was wondering, if all players had no cards in their library and you cast a card like [Skyscribing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSkyscribing%5d) that makes everyone draw a card, does this make the game a draw  or is there a draw order and one person wins?

I think it has the same order as resolving like [Living Death](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiving%20Death%5d) but I would like to get this cleared.

Comment: You are right about the draw order, but it doesn't actually make a difference since the game checks if players tried to draw from an empty deck all at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a draw.

A player does not lose *immediately* when drawing a card from an empty library:

> 704.5b If a player attempted to draw a card from a library with no cards in it since the last time state-based actions were checked, that player loses the game.

State-based actions are not checked until after Skyscribing resolves completely:

> 704.3. Whenever a player would get priority (see rule 117, “Timing and Priority”), the game checks for any of the listed conditions for state-based actions, then performs all applicable state-based actions simultaneously as a single event.
>
> 117.2e Resolving spells and abilities may instruct players to make choices or take actions, or may allow players to activate mana abilities. Even if a player is doing so, no player has priority while a spell or ability is resolving. See rule 608, “Resolving Spells and Abilities.”

State-based actions will make all players lose the game, and 104.4 applies in that situation:

> 104.4. There are several ways for the game to be a draw.
>
> 104.4a If all the players remaining in a game lose simultaneously, the game is a draw.

So it's a draw. (Unless one of the players has an effect akin to [Obstinate Familiar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bObstinate%20Familiar%5d), in which case they win the game as the only surviving player.)

Comment: "(Unless one of the players has an effect akin to Obstinate Familiar, in which case they win the game as the only surviving player.)" Well, may win the game. Giving the wording of Obstinate Familiar, not losing is optional :)